# HAProxy rules and aws instance access based on incoming corporate and public requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy, haproxy, amazon-route53

i have two subnets in aws: sub-private and sub-public and i have instances spun up in each instances. Now i have to configure ec2 instance's security group and haproxy configuration to allow incoming requests as follows:

http request from any of my corporate networks should allow access to both private and public subnet instances. but http request from rest of the world (other than my corporate ips) should be allowed access to only instances from sub-public subnet.

currently i have plan to setup two ec2 instances with haproxy installed and configure them as follows:
  priv-haproxy server will have aws security group to allow only from range of ip addresses of my corporate network, and will have haconfig.cfg rules to forward requests only to my sub-private instances.
  same way, pub-haproxy server will have aws security group to allow 'any' ip addresses with acl to point to pub-subnet instances.

Finally i will have Route53 record-set with CNAME created in public zone to point to priv-proxy from host names of sub-private instances and pub-proxy from host names of pub-subnet instances.

Now, my question is do we have anyother better way to handle this scenario without using two proxy instances? can just one proxy instance with correct rules solve this problem?

***Updated:***

this is how now i have configured my aws security group and haproxy configuration and going with just one haproxy instance (not two):

1. "aws security group" for haproxy server allows all incoming http request (0.0.0.0/0)
2. haproxy config has the following entry:

> ```
> frontend public
>   bind *:80
>         acl host_showcase hdr(host) -i demo.example.org
>         use_backend showcase if host_showcase
>
> frontend private
>   bind *:80
>         acl white_list src 106.220.4.153
>         tcp-request content accept if white_list
>         tcp-request content reject
>         acl host_qa hdr(host) -i qa.example.org
>         use_backend qa if host_qa
>
> backend showcase
>   server showcase 172.21.4.100
> backend qa
>   server qa 172.21.3.200
> ```

After this configuration, my application seems to work fine. i.e. public frontend apps works for all ip addresses and private frontend apps work only for the white-listed ip addresses. great!!

But now my question is, is it a good security practice as i have allowed all ip addresses at my proxy instance security group. Am i missing anything here?

Comment: Yes, one HAProxy can be used, with the security group allowing all and using source IP address ACLs in HAProxy config, and `http-request deny unless ...` the private address range matches, for the private back-ends.  You should probably try configuring it and update the question if you get stuck, or provide more detail to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: More detail would be great. Like why are you putting Public stuff in a public subnet and corporate stuff in a private subnet? Is this hosting the same app/content?

Comment: public subnet is a demo environment which we use for our external clients to experience our app and private subnet is for our internal access only, for development and testing the app.

Comment: @AlagesanPalani I don't think you are a really following best practices here. It looks like you have two EC2 instances. And maybe the config/data is different between them. So really they should have the same topology but with different security groups.  For example, I would use a ELB/ALB and drop the HAProxy. You can use DNS to get you to the correct ELB. The ELB will be in the public subnet. The EC2 instances will be in your private subnet.  Your ELB will be the only thing that can talk the EC2 instances.